# What is clients internal state representation?

Tags: transactions, wallets

I am reading the Mastering Ethereum book and came across this paragraph:

> For EOA addresses, or rather for any address that isn’t flagged as a contract
> on the blockchain, Ethereum will record a state change, adding the value
> you sent to the balance of the address. If the address has not been seen
> before, it will be added to the client’s internal representation of the state and
> its balance initialized to the value of your payment.

I find this part confusing:

> If the address has not been seen
> before, it will be added to the client’s internal representation of the state and
> its balance initialized to the value of your payment.

What does this actually mean?

It looks like if you send a payment to an address does not exist, it is not lost but somehow added to an internal state? And what is this internal state and what is it used for? Or am I reading this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how the actual implementation works for EOA balances, but from the blockchain's point of view, all non-contract addresses exist (or don't exist) in the same manner. Any address (which is not reserved by a contract already) is a valid EOA address.

You can send Ethers to an address which has never been used. You don't need to know whether someone has the private key for the address or not. Of course, if nobody ever has the private key, the sent assets are lost, since nobody can recover them.

In fact, it's quite normal for security-sensitive users to create a private key offline and calculate its public address offline. Then they can distribute that address to other users and anyone can send assets to it. Whenever the owner wants to recover those assets (for example to move them elsewhere), he can use his private key to sign the first transaction out of that address.

Comment: I see. Then I think the books language is just confusing because the following does not make much sense to me, and looks like something different from what you explained" it will be added to the client’s internal representation of the state and its balance initialized to the value of your payment"

Comment: I don't see that as conflicting statement. I interpret that as a somewhat implementation detail, but can't really be sure.

Comment: I read that to mean something would happen to the client who initiated the transaction to unseen address...ie "it will be added to the client's internal representation...etc"